# Why JQueryUI does not work on salesforce standard input elements?

Tags: jquery-ui, salesforce, visualforce

I am having trouble using JQueryUI with salesforce standard elements. Basically, I want to auto suggest the record names to the user, instead of the user clicking on the salesforce search button.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!MyRecord.ChildRecord__c}" id="inpId" required="true/>

<script>
   jq$(document.getElementById('{!$Component.inpId}')).autocomplete( { 
            minLength: 2,
            autoFocus: true,
            source: mySource
   });
</script>
```

Therefore, I want to know if anyone attempted to use JQueryUI with standard salesforce input elements. In my case, the JQueryUI events are not firing for salesforce elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the reason why JQeuryUI was not working on SalesForce standard input element. I was trying to use JQueryUI autocomplete on the input element. The action function that was supposed to be invoked was not called because I did not have

```
<apex:actionFunction immediate="true" />
```

That is we must have immediate=true attribute set so that action function is called immediately. If we do not have this attribute set, SalesForce tries to validate all the standard input elements and if the validation fails, action function is never called.

Answer (score 2):

`{!$Component.[elementid]}` doesn't always work for me; I'm not sure why. I prefer to use the Attribute Ends With Selector (http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).

Try something like this:

```
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/18.0/connection.js" />
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/18.0/apex.js" />

<script>
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    j$(document).ready(function(){init();});

    function init()
    {
        var mySourceText = "ActionScript AppleScript Asp BASIC C "
           + "C++ Clojure COBOL ColdFusion Erlang Fortran Groovy "
           + "Haskell Java JavaScript Lisp Perl PHP Python Ruby "
           + "Scala Scheme";

        var mySource = mySourceText.split(" ");

        j$("[id$='myInput']").autocomplete({ 
            minLength: 2,
            autoFocus: true,
            source: function(request, response){ 
                    response(GetSourceAjaxAPI(request.term)); }
        });
    }

    function GetSourceAjaxAPI(s)
    {
        var result = sforce.apex.execute("TestAutocomplete", 
                     "GetAutocompleteValuesAjaxAPI", {SearchTerm:s});
        return result;
    }
</script>

<apex:form >
    <apex:pageblock >
        <apex:pageblocksection >
            <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                <apex:inputfield id="myInput" value="{!Contact.FirstName}" />
            </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
        </apex:pageblocksection>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
```

Controller:

```
global class TestAutocomplete 
{
    global TestAutocomplete(ApexPages.StandardController myStandardController) {}

    webservice static List<String> 
        GetAutocompleteValuesAjaxAPI(String SearchTerm)
    {            
        String mySourceText = 'ActionScript AppleScript Asp BASIC C '
           + 'C++ Clojure COBOL ColdFusion Erlang Fortran Groovy '
           + 'Haskell Java JavaScript Lisp Perl PHP Python Ruby '
           + 'Scala Scheme';

        List<String> mySourceList = mySourceText.split(' ');
        List<String> myReturnList = new List<String>();

        for(String s : mySourceList)
        {
            if(s.contains(SearchTerm)){ myReturnList.add(s); }
        }

        return myReturnList;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps,
Matt

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say. We already ran into this issue and are using the solution you outlined. But, the problem seems to be with salesforce. Some how the autocomplete events like source, search etc never gets called. The autocomplete works if you have a static source (like an array). But, it is not working if I dynamically invoke an action function.

Comment: Have you tried using [Javascript Remoting](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm) to get your data?

Comment: Yes, we considered that option.

Comment: One of the issues with using the `$Component.Id` notation with jQuery is that the SFDC generated IDs often contain colons (:) which are not allowed as part of an ID selector in jQuery. They need to be escaped and it can be a bit of a pain. I tend to choose the non-pure route and just give my inputs a specific class!

Comment: I tried this work around. My code works on standard html input element, but it does not work on apex:inputField. I think my code conflicts with salesforce client script. This is only a guess though.

Comment: Try using the AJAX API instead of Javascript Remoting, if that's not working for you. I'll edit the above post with an example.

Comment: I decided to use standard HTML input element and handle the validation inside the controller. It worked for me. There is no way I could make apex inputField work with JqueryUI for dynamic source.